# Pointer/struct (C) - IDE: Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, struct

I've a problem with my code. I have to input data into a struct for n times.
To choose the cardinality of the struct during the declaration of the variables, I write: struct table T[DIM]; but.. DIM is a constant...so ... I would like to make somehow, dynamic the constant. I would do this, using a pointer.
Then...:

```
const int DIM
int *p=&DIM
```

Next, I'm going to load the struct with data using a for. But before starting the for I want to ask what is the cardinality of the struct in this way:

```
printf("\nEnter the number of flights to manage");
scanf("%d", &*p)
```

Everything seems to work but while I run the insertion cycle, in the second or third cycle, this crash.
Now I will enter the relevant code part:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <process.h>

struct table {
    int cod;
    char departure[20];
    char arrival[20];
    int tot_seats;
    int seats_busy;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
const int DIM;
int *p=&DIM
struct table T[DIM];
int menu=0;
int menu1=0;
int I=0;
int TAB=0;
int flight;
int cont=0;

printf("---------------------------Airports------------------------\n\n");

while(menu!=3){
    printf("\nWelcome to the software! Choose the most suitable function for your needs: \n \n");
    printf("Do you run an airport or travel agency? Answer by typing the number associated with the response\n");
    printf("1) Airports\n");                                                  /*Apro il primo menù*/
    printf("2) Travel agency\n");
    printf("3) Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &menu);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------- \n \n");

    switch(menu){
    case 1: system("cls");
            printf("\nYou have chosen the airport option\n-- You can now load the table --\n \n");


printf("\nEnter the number of flights to manage\n");
            TAB=1;
            for(I=0;I<DIM;I++){
                printf("\n You are completing the line %d \n", I+1);
                getchar();

                printf("\nEnter the departure city:");
                gets(&T[I].departure);

                printf("\nEnter the city of arrival:");
                gets(&T[I].arrival);

                printf("\nEnter the flight code:");
                scanf("%d", &T[I].cod);

                printf("\nEnter the total number of flight seats:");
                scanf("%d", &T[I].tot_seats);
            }
            printf("CODE -- DEPARTURE -- ARRIVAL-- TOT_SEATS\n");
            for(I=0;I<DIM;I++){
                printf("%d -- %s -- %s -- %d \n", T[I].cod, T[I].partenza,T[I].arrivo,T[I].tot_posti);
            }
            break;
```

Also eclipse tells me that in correspondence with:

```
gets(&T[I].departure);
```

and

```
gets(&T[I].arrival);
```

there is an error: passing argument 1 of 'gets' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default].

How can I fix both errors? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `gets(&T[I].departure);` --> `gets(T[I].departure);`, Also `DIM` is uninitialized. `gets` has been abolished.

Comment: If you want to change `DIM` at run time, you shouldn't declare it `const`. If the array `T` should have variable many members depending on run time information (i.e. `DIM`) you should allocate the memory needed for it (or use variable length arrays). Probably you should read a book about C.

Comment: I know @Krom ; I started studying the C only last week.
I didn't understand your advice. 
I understand that I can declare DIM as variable but if i do this at this point of code:
'for(I=0;I<DIM;I++){
                printf("%d -- %s -- %s -- %d \n", T[I].cod, T[I].partenza,T[I].arrivo,T[I].tot_posti);
            }'
it crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why malloc has been created :)
You can allocate dynamically an array with the size, given as an input, like the number of flights in your example.
if you have p flights you can create a table

```
T = (int) malloc(p*sizeof(int);
```

then you can iterate through your table from  0 to p.
regards

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I did not understand at what point of the code I should include this string.

Comment: But i use a struct not a simple bidimensional array.

Comment: Then you can do a malloc of any type of data such as (my_struct *) malloc(p*sizeof(my_struct))

Comment: Instead of "My_struct" do I have to enter "table" or "T"?